# PHP/HTML form processing

Tags: php, html

The assignment is to create an html form where the user enters the required information, and process the form data via PHP to display the output using $_post method. I can't seem to get the output right, it just basically displays the php code that I wrote. any insight is greatly appreciated
 Note: The html code is lengthy, but I'm sure it's correct. My problem is with the PHP(next) code.
the following is the output:

```
0){ $Name = trim($_POST['name']); $adr = trim($_POST['address']); $City = trim($_POST['city']); $state = trim($_POST['state']); $zip = trim($_POST['zip']); $phone = trim($_POST['phone']); $email = trim($_POST['email']); $err = array(); if($Name == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your name"; } if($adr == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your address"; } if($City == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your city"; } if($state == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your State"; } if($zip == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your zip"; } if($phone == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your phone number"; } if($email == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your email"; } if(count($err) > 0){ foreach($err as $value){ echo"$value
"; } echo " Go Back"; } else{ //header("Location:HTMLform.html"); echo "Name: " . $_POST["name"]; echo "Address: " . $_POST["address"] ; echo "City: " . $_POST["city"] ; echo "State: " . $_POST["state"]; echo "Zip: " . $_POST["zip"]; echo "Phone: " . $_POST["phone"]; echo "Email: " . $_POST["email"]; } } ?>
```

**page 1 (HTML FORM)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Coffee Order</title>
 </head>
 <body><h1>The Coffee House</h1>


<div>
    <div><h3>Order Form</h3></div>
    <form name='frmInput' action="process.php" method="post">
    <table><tr><td>Coffee:</td>
        <td><select name="coffeeCode" id="Coffee">
<option value="">Select Coffee:</option><option value="bv">Boca Villa ($7.99/lb) 
</option>
<option value="sbr">South Beach Rhythm ($8.99/lb)</option>
<option value="pp">Pumpkin Paradise ($8.99/lb)</option>
<option value="ss">Sumatran Sunset ($9.99/lb)</option>
<option value="bb">Bali Batur ($10.95/lb)</option>
<option value="dd">Double Dark ($9.95/lb)</option></select></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        Type:</td>
        <td>
<input type="radio" name="coffeeType" value="caf">Regular<br/>
<input type="radio" name="coffeeType" value="decaf">Decaffeinated
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity (in pounds):</td>
        <td>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" maxlength="3" size="3" id="Quantity">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="Name">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E-mail address:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="Email">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Telephone #:</td>
        <td>
    <input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="14" size="14" id="Telephone">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="Address">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="city" id="City">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>State:</td>
        <td>
<input type="text" name="state" maxlength="2" size="2" 
style="text-transform: uppercase" id="State">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Zip:</td>
        <td>
<input type="text" name="zip" maxlength="10" size="10" id="Zip">
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td><td><input    type="reset"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form></div></body>
</html>
```

php code:

```
<?php
if (count($_POST) > 0){

$Name = trim($_POST['name']);
$adr = trim($_POST['address']);
$City = trim($_POST['city']);
$state = trim($_POST['state']);
$zip = trim($_POST['zip']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$err = array();

if($Name == ''){
$err[] = "Please enter your name";
}
if($adr == ''){
$err[] = "Please enter your address";
}
if($City == ''){
$err[] = "Please enter your city";
}
if($state == ''){
$err[] = "Please enter your State";
}
if($zip == ''){
$err[] = "Please enter your zip";
}
if($phone == ''){
$err[] = "Please enter your phone number";
}
if($email == ''){
$err[] = "Please enter your email";
}

if(count($err) > 0){
   foreach($err as $value){
   echo"$value<br/>";
}
echo "<a href='HTMLform.html'> Go Back</a>";
}
 else{
//header("Location:HTMLform.html");
 echo "Name: " . $_POST["name"];

 echo "Address: " . $_POST["address"] ;

 echo "City: " . $_POST["city"] ;

 echo "State: " . $_POST["state"];

 echo "Zip: " . $_POST["zip"];

 echo "Phone: " . $_POST["phone"];

 echo "Email: " . $_POST["email"];
 }

}
 ?>
```

Comment: Also, could you just update the question with the updated code you are using. Just copy paste the exact code.

Comment: I can't think of any reason for this as its working for me. I'm using php version 5.5.9, if that helps you in some way.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense why that output would start where it does....i've been at it for hours

Comment: I got the same output when there was a space between `<?` and `php` but after I changed it, it worked fine.

Comment: Weird... i'll eventually just type it all line by line and hope for different results lol

Comment: I copied that script into a previous assignment's shell and it gave no output at all

Answer (score 0):

- PHP file are saved with .php extension and has an opening of

  PHP code should be at the top of the page, before any HTML tag

  Instead of using $variable == '' to check if it's empty, use function called `empty($variable)` that return true if empty

  You are doing a redirect in the first line of the `else` statement, so the rest of the code won't be executed, therefore the echo part will never be reached. Put this `header("Location:HTMLform.html");` as the last statement in the `else` scope

Comment: It's two different pages, one is just HTML, and the second page is the PHP script that processes the html. The error I'm getting is I don't get output. When the submit button is hit, this displays

Comment: Oh okay, I though it was one page. Anw Check my third bullet, I explained why you don't have output

Comment: 0){ //read in input $Name = trim($_POST['name']); $adr = trim($_POST['address']); $City = trim($_POST['city']); $state = trim($_POST['state']); $zip = trim($_POST['zip']); $phone = trim($_POST['telephone']); $email = trim($_POST['email']); $err = array(); if($Name == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your name"; } if($adr == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your address"; } if($City == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your city"; } if($state == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your State"; } if($zip == ''){ $err[] = "Please enter your zip"; } if($phone == '')*I couldn't fit the whole thing but you get the idea

Comment: Well, I only recently added that, I thought the reason I was getting this problem was because that wasn't there.....buuuut I clearly don't get it

Comment: Header do a redirect, so whenever you call it, the rest of the code won't execute and the page will be redirected

Comment: A redirect? I moved the header line to the very last statement in the else....no difference in the results

Comment: count($err)) why do you have 2 closing parenthesis ? remove one close parenthesis

Comment: Thanks...but it didn't effect the output at all :( I just can't figure out why it's doing what it's doing

Comment: Are you saving the file as .php ? and the php file should start with <?php and not <? space php

Comment: Yeah, it was originally without the space...but I'm at the point where i'll try any and everything

Comment: Can u tell me how the file are saved and what are their names ?

Comment: html--> HTMLform.html  php-> process.php

Comment: Not sure how much it would help but here's a link to what it's SUPPOSED to do....https://district.bluegrass.kctcs.edu/thomas.papa/coffee/Coffee.php

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code.

- There is a space between `<?` tag and `php` in line 1. Remove that
- There is no closing curly brace for this , `if (count($_POST) > 0) {`. Add a closing curly brace before the ending `?>` tag.
- You have the name field of telephone set to 'phone'.

  So find all lines having this

  ```
   $_POST['telephone']
  ```

  and change it to

  ```
   $_POST['phone']
  ```

Also, If you want to see the results, comment out

```
  header('Location:HTMLForm.html');
```

Comment: Tried...exact same results =/

Comment: Its working fine for me on my local system. :/ 
Are you on linux or windows ?

Comment: Are you getting the same output ? coz its working in my local system. Can you please comment the exact output here or update the question with the exact output maybe ?

Comment: Updating the question incoming

Answer (score 0):

old

```
// is this suppose to be an array?
    $err = array();
    if($_POST['name'] == null){
        array_push($err,'error stuff stuff stuff');
    }
    print_r($err);

// if not array
    $err = '';
    if($_POST['name'] == null){
        $err.= 'error stuff stuff stuff';
    }
```

Also, What are you trimming from the post?